# What exactly does EnableWindowsTargeting do?

Tags: .net-core

I had a problem that I could not compile a .NET 6 project because it targets Windows but I'm working on MacOS. This is part of the .csproj file:

```
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net60-windows</TargetFramework>
<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
```

When looking at the console output I saw the following interesting:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(90,5):
> error NETSDK1100: To build a project targeting Windows on this
> operating system, set the EnableWindowsTargeting property to true

If I just modify my project to this:

```
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType> 
<TargetFramework>net60-windows</TargetFramework> 
<UseWPF>true</UseWPF> 
<EnableWindowsTargeting>true</EnableWindowsTargeting>
```

It then successfully compiles, but now I'm wondering what this actually does? I can't find that much documentation around that property, and the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1100) only say it will download a runtime pack, but what exactly does that mean? I thought that when you specified `<TargetFramework>netXX-windows</TargetFramework>` it would, well, only run on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [dotnet docs on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props.md#enablewindowstargeting), setting this property to `true` allows you to build Windows apps on non-Windows platforms.